# Deployment on server for docker application

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose

I am new to docker and deployment.

I have project in which I have backend in a docker container. Is there anyway I can deploy it just by copying my required files(backend code) and docker-compose.yml file? It would be great if you can provide online servers which allows me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a container with your backend code and host it on a image registry such as [Docker Hub](http://hub.docker.com) or [Amazon Elastic Container Registry](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/). In your docker-compose file, you reference the image from hosted at the registry.

Here's the documentation for doing this on ECR. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html